Forward propogation of rotated clifford gates in lattice surgery
In A Game of Surface Codes (arXiv), I have been trying to understand the process that is described for forward propogating rotated clifford gates through other rotated clifford gates, and either I am making an error in these calculations, or missing something obvious. It's stated that

where $P_{\theta}=e^{-iP\theta}$
In the case of the commutating one, it is obvious. However, using an example, I cannot reproduce the bottom one.
If we take $$e^{-iZ\frac{\pi}{4}}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}} & 0\\
0 & e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
\end{bmatrix}, e^{-iX\theta}= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -i\sin(\theta)\\
-i\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
then $$e^{-iX\theta}e^{-iZ\frac{\pi}{4}}= \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(\theta) & -ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\theta)\\
-ie^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\theta) &e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
where operation order is reverse of those in the pictures, as the circuit reads left to right, so multiplication order is the reverse
Now taking $iXZ=Y$, $$e^{-iY\theta}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Taking this and right multiplying, as the second line in the image shows, by $e^{-Zi\frac{\pi}{4}}$ gives $$e^{-iZ\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{iY\theta}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(\theta) & -e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\theta)\\
e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\theta) &e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
The off diagonal entries do not match, and I even did it in the revese order, ie not the order that the circuit diagrams would suggest. Am I missing something obvious here? When all is said an done, we need $i$ on the diagonal.
According to the paper, the end result should be
$$e^{-iX\theta}e^{-iZ\frac{\pi}{4}}=e^{-iZ\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-iXZ\theta}$$
It could be that swapping $X$ and $Z$ for the product operation isn't correct, but even doing it the other way around doesn't work.

Firstly, the term in the diagram is $iPP' = iZX$ not $iXZ$, and so your off diagonal terms in $\exp(PP'\theta)$ should have the opposite sign. After that, use the identity that $e^{-i \pi/4} = e^{-i \pi/2} e^{i \pi/4} = -i e^{i \pi/4}$.

Ah I see I shifted the order of X and Z for the exponential function. Thank you. I actually tried to use that identity before but because I'd had the order wrong I assumed I was on the wrong track :/
